# Deleting a folder from blob container

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I need to delete a folder from a blob container in Azure storage account. The folder structure is as follows:

```
container -> failed -> profiles
```

I am connecting to the container as follows:

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = StorageAccountManager.getStorageAccount(ConnectionString));
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(container_name);
```

I am trying to refer to the specific folder as follows:

```
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(failed + "/" + directory);
```

I also tried the follows ways:

```
((CloudBlob)blob).DeleteIfExists(); 
blob.DeleteIfExists();
blob.DeleteAsync();
```

but none of these are deleting the folder in my blob storage. Am I missing something or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to use 'GetDirectoryReference("your folder name")' and then use deleteIfExists

Comment: what should I assign the GetDirectoryReference to?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727829/how-to-delete-a-folder-within-an-azure-blob-container

Comment: @Llazar this link worked. is it possible to parse through all the folders to check in which folder this folder is present?

Comment: Programatically is posible to iterate through folders files but you need to remember that the Azure Storage doesn't have the sense of folders.

Answer (score 1):

Folders in Azure Storage aren't really created or deleted, they exist as long as there are blobs stored in them. The way to delete a folder is to retrieve all blobs in it using `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync` and calling `DeleteIfExists()` on each of them.