# Delete Directory containing BLOB from Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

The task here is to delete the folders inside the storage account from a Logic App. I am seeking a similar action as "Delete Blob" to delete the folders also. For example, directory structure is like

> XYZ -> 2021-06-14 -> filename.json

I want to delete the folder itself but unable to find a direct action for the same. Any work arounds are also accepted.

Comment: Is the answer provided was helpful for you ? if so could you please accept the answer ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) as solution for your ask. This could be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links where you have some details about deletion of files or folder inside blob using Logic App

1)https://lucavallarelli.altervista.org/blog/gdpr-logic-app-delete-blob/

2)https://sameeraman.wordpress.com/2017/08/25/logic-apps-delete-files-older-than-x-days-from-a-blob-storage/

Answer (score 0):

Azure Blob Storage does not really have the concept of folders. The hierarchy is very simple:  **storage account > container > blob**.

I have 2 ways for this

**WAY - 1**
we can delete a specific Blob from the container by using delete method as follows:

```
public  void DeleteBlob()
{
 var _containerName = "appcontainer";
 string _storageConnection = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString");
 CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_storageConnection);
 CloudBlobClient _blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
 CloudBlobContainer _cloudBlobContainer = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(_containerName);
 CloudBlockBlob _blockBlob = _cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("f115a610-a899-42c6-bd3f-74711eaef8d5-.jpg");
  
 //delete blob from container
_blockBlob.Delete();
}
```

Delete Action will be:

```
public ActionResult DeleteBlob()
{
 imageService.DeleteBlob();
 return View();
}
```

**WAY - 2**
Listing the blobs within the required container, you can then delete them individually

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("your storage account");
CloudBlobContainer container = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("pictures");
foreach (IListBlobItem blob in container.GetDirectoryReference("users").ListBlobs(true))
{
    if (blob.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlob) || blob.GetType().BaseType == typeof(CloudBlob))
    {
        ((CloudBlob)blob).DeleteIfExists();
    }
}
```

For further more analysis you can refer the following links [link 1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-download-and-delete-blob-files-in-azure-storage/) [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727829/how-to-delete-a-folder-within-an-azure-blob-container).