# How to delete Blob folders using Java SDK v12

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

I'm trying to simulate a move action (as I haven't seen any move method as such) by copying and deleting blobs between two directories within the same container.

For example, inside `container A`, moving `.csv` blobs from `Folder_1` into `Folder_2` and then deleting `/year/month/day` folder structure from `Folder 1`

```
container A
|_ Folder_1
|_ _ _/year/month/day/a.csv
|
|_ Folder_2
```

What I currently have looks like the following piece of code:

```java
String blobUrl = "Folder_1 a.csv blob url"
String blobName = "a.csv"
BlobContainerClient outputContainerClient = outputBlobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("Container A");
// Folder_1 client
BlobClient tempBlobClient=outputContainerClient.getBlobClient("Folder_1/year/month/day/" + blobName);
// Folder_2 client
BlobClient destBlobClient=outputContainerClient.getBlobClient("Folder_2/year/month/day/" + blobName);
// Copy from Folder_1 to Folder_2                
destBlobClient.beginCopy(blobUrl,null);
// Delete Folder_1      
tempBlobClient.delete();
```

The problem is that the `tempBlobClient.delete()` deletes the original `a.csv` but not the directory structure of `Folder_1/year/month/day/`. It leaves that path without a file but the directories remain undeleted.

Any ideas on how to deal with this problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is your storage account ADLS Gen2 or a regular storage account? From the description it looks like ADLS Gen2 but want to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gaurav!  It's ADLS Gen2

Comment: For ADLS Gen2 Storage Accounts, please use `azure-storage-file-datalake` SDK instead of regular blob storage SDK. You can find more information about the SDK here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/storage-file-datalake-readme?view=azure-java-stable. HTH.

Comment: This could be tried for java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70719419/delete-a-folder-in-azure-blob-storage-with-java/70719460#70719460

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code

```
var connectionString = "blob-connection-string";
var containerName = "container-name";
var folderPath = "folder1/subfolder/sub-subfolder";

var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
var blobItems = blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: folderPath);
await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in blobItems)
{
     BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);
     await blobClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
}
```

For more details refer [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727829/how-to-delete-a-folder-within-an-azure-blob-container).