# Delete a folder in Azure Blob Storage with Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

How to delete a folder in azure blob storage. When I attempt to delete a folder, I see the below error:

> com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException: Status code 409,
> "﻿`DirectoryIsNotEmpty`This
> operation is not permitted on a non-empty directory.
> RequestId:195b3f66-601e-0071-2edb-094790000000
> Time:2022-01-15T06:47:55.8443865Z"
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at
> com.azure.core.http.rest.RestProxy.instantiateUnexpectedException(RestProxy.java:389)
> at
> com.azure.core.http.rest.RestProxy.lambda$ensureExpectedStatus$7(RestProxy.java:444)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the below version is the most optimized one. But it appears to work:

```
public static void deleteAtLocation(BlobContainerClient container, String historical) {
    if (checkIfPathExists(container, historical)) {
        List<BlobItem> collect = container.listBlobsByHierarchy(historical).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (BlobItem blobItem : collect) {
            String name = blobItem.getName();
            if (name.endsWith("/")) {
                deleteAtLocation(container, name);
            } else container.getBlobClient(name).delete();
        }
        container.getBlobClient(historical.substring(0, historical.length() - 1)).delete();
    }
}

public static boolean checkIfPathExists(BlobContainerClient container, String filePath) {
    BlobClient blobClient = container.getBlobClient(filePath);
    return blobClient.exists();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the prefix and delete all the sub blobs, the folder will be deleted by default if there are no actual blobs inside it.

```
public void deleteBlobs(BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient, String path){

    log.info("Deleting all blobs at {} in container {}", path, blobContainerClient.getBlobContainerName());

    ListBlobsOptions options = new ListBlobsOptions().setPrefix(path)
            .setDetails(new BlobListDetails().setRetrieveDeletedBlobs(false).setRetrieveSnapshots(false));
    blobContainerClient.listBlobs(options, null).iterator()
            .forEachRemaining(item -> blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(item.getName()).delete());
}
```