# Where does Azurite store blobs, queues and tables on mac?

Tags: azurite, azure-storage-explorer

I'm developing an Azure Function on VSCode. I see that a bunch of files are created in my workspace folder. However, even if I delete them, when I open Azure Storage Explorer, I still see a bunch of containers etc. How can I delete all of them in one command?

[image: azure storage explorer files]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders in Azure Storage aren't really created or deleted (Azure Blob storage does not have a concept of folders and everything inside the container is considered a blob including the folders. You can easily delete a folder including all its contents in [Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/storage-explorer/)) , they exist as long as there are blobs stored in them. The way to delete a folder is to retrieve all blobs in it using ListBlobsSegmentedAsync and calling DeleteIfExists() on each of them.

Ref: There is a similar discussion threads here, refer to the suggestions mentioned in this [Q&A thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/466968/remove-azure-blob-storage-folders-with-sdk) and [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727829/how-to-delete-a-folder-within-an-azure-blob-container)